# hil_message must be declared

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I'm trying to compile an oracle forms module but I'm getting the error.

```
identified 'HIL_MESSAGE' must be declared
```

I'm a newbie in Oracle Forms but I'd like to know how to compile it's depencies (I guess that this package is available at HeadStart) to solve this error. The call at my program is:

```
PROCEDURE LogError (p_errorrec IN hil_Message.message_rectype);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hil_message is a table in the Headstart schema. If there is a synonym in the database, you just need the privilege to select from the table. Ask the DBA to grant you the privilege:

```
grant select on Hil_message to [your user];
```

Comment: Where can I find this lib?

Comment: Well it seems to me that the forms are using Headstart. So you must have some Headstart libraries around in your source repository?

Comment: Sorry but I'm so newbie on this. in my database there is a synonym with this name HIL_MESSAGE but I have no ideia wich librany I need to attach

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong with the library. hil_message is actually a table in the Headstart schema. If there is a synonym in the database, you just need the privilege to select from the table.